# How to get results fastly with 'column1+column2=@variable'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016. I have a table more than 10m rows. When I want to search with the query show here, it is very slow.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.table_name
(
    Col1 int NOT NULL,
    Col2 int NULL,
    Col3 char(2) NULL,
    Col4 char(15) NULL,
    Col5 varchar(8) NULL,
    Col6 varchar(12) NULL,
    Col7 varchar(8) NULL,
    Col8 int NULL,
    Col9 int NULL,
    Col10 varchar(16) NOT NULL
) ON PRIMARY

SELECT
    colum3 + column4 
FROM
    tablename 
WHERE
    column3 + column4 = @variable
```

What index method should I use to speed up this query? (of type varchar in two columns)

Comment: Please post a schema definition and EXPLAIN - without those, we're probably just guessing. 
As the columns are VARCHAR, your best option is to use full text search indexing.

Comment: No index would help with that clause. Why can't you do `Column1 = @Variable1 AND Column2 = @Variable2`?

Comment: For example.The value I'm looking for is 'abc123'. but 'abc' and '123' values ​​are stored in different columns in the table. @Larnu

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though. Why not `Column1 = @Variable1 AND Column2 = @Variable2`?

Comment: The value I'm searching for may sometimes not contain a value from column3. @Larna

Comment: That sounds like a Normalization issue, do you by chance see a way to design one single purpose per column?

Comment: A query using a function based value in the where clause will always be slow as the optimizer has to compute that value for every row. In the actual form, you should also expect invalid result as `Col3 + Col4` will return null if either value is null. Thus, if `Col4` would be equal to `@variable` and you expect this result while `Col3` is null, it won't be returned. You should always prefer this form `Concat(Col3, Col4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could consider a computed column and indexing that.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD concat_column AS
  CONCAT(column1 + column2);

CREATE INDEX ix_concat_column ON dbo.tablename(concat_column)
  INCLUDE ...
```

Not sure an index on the separate columns would be of much help, since it would still have to perform the concat on every pair (think `'Rhy' + 'thm'` is the same as `'R' + 'hythm'`).

Comment: Why not use `PERSISTED [NOT] NULL`?

Comment: Can't I solve this problem by creating an index without creating a 3rd column? What is the best practice for this problem?

Comment: @Dai What would be the benefit of persisting it and _also_ indexing it?

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker It wouldn't need to recompute the concat in future queries.

Comment: @ResulHastürk I don't think SQL Server supports indexes on columns that don't exist, and you can't create a function-based index.

Comment: @Dai the result of the concat is stored _in the index_, so it is only recomputed on write.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker _"the concat is stored in the index, so it is only recomputed on write"_ - you're assuming the index will always be used 100% of the time for all queries over that table - which rarely is the case. Using a persisted computed column just saves the most trouble (not to mention allowing the column to be used in other situations, such as FOREIGN KEY and CHECK constraints).

Comment: @Dai for this query, I would hope it would be. You're assuming this concatenated column would be used by any other query. Anyway, you asked why I didn't say persisted, I've told you, if we have more context we could probably make a better decision.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker The OP is using `SELECT *` so all bets are off w.r.t. index selection.

Comment: @Dai Well that's a different issue altogether. If we're going to recommend PERSISTED to encourage using SELECT *, I'm not down for that at all, sorry.

Comment: Actually 'select *' is not required. 'select column3+column4' is sufficient.

Comment: Since the computed column is `Deterministic` and `Precise` there is no need to persist the column. @RhytmWasaLurker is right.

Comment: @Dai the index would be used anytime the computed column would be part of a where clause, even when not calling the computed column directly. (Ie: `where Contat(Col3, Col4) = @variable` instead of `where CC_Col = @variable`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no nice way to do this - but you have a few options.

The problem is that the query has to concatenate col3 and col4 for every row in the database and compare it to your variable. The concatenation means it won't use an index. The time to do that will increase linearly with the number of rows.

Firstly, if you create indexes on column3 and on column4, and change the query to be

```
select concat(col3, col4) 
from table_name 
where (
   col3 like left(@variable, 3)
   or col4 like left(@variable, 3)
and concat(col3, col4) = @variable
```

you should get a decent improvement in speed. That's because the first where clause can use an index, and *should* reduce the total number of rows on which the query has to concatenate col3 and col4. I've suggested the first 3 characters of @variable - adjust that to whatever works.

The second option is to create a view which concatenates column3 and column4 into a new column, and [create an index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16) on that column. That *should* be incredibly fast.

Comment: You can't create a non-clustered index on a view unless you also create a _clustered_ index on that view, and indexed views have a pretty narrow use case.

Answer (score 0):

The model suggests that Col3 and Col4 values are always 2 and 15 char in lenght.

If this is the case, you could add an index including both column and using them seperatly in the where clause.

It will remains to figure out how `Null` values should be handled.

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_myindex ON dbo.tablename(Col1, Col2);
GO

SELECT
    Concat(colum3, column4) 
FROM
    tablename 
WHERE
    column3 = left(@variable,2) and (column4 = right(@variable,15)
```

---

Solution handling `Null` values based on the same assumptions.

```sql
SELECT
    Concat(colum3, column4) 
FROM
    tablename 
WHERE
    ( Len(@variable) = 17 AND 
      column3 = left(@variable,2) and (column4 = right(@variable,15) )
    OR
    ( Len(@variable) = 2 AND
      column3 = @variable AND column4 is null )
    OR
    ( Len(@variable) = 15 AND
      column3 is null AND column4 = @variable )
```